# Is there a technical reason for having Office 365 on my PC?

Tags: office365

I noticed a few days ago, that the system installed Office 365 on my Windows PC.  At the start of the process, I thought it was updating my Office 2016 installation.

The reason I haven't upgraded my Office to a newer version is that I do not want the cloud to have a copy of what I do on my PC.

I know why Microsoft would want me to use the Cloud version.  I have uninstalled it.  I want to know if there is a technical reason to have left it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason I haven't upgraded my Office to a newer version is that I do not want the cloud to have a copy of what I do on my PC.
>
> I know why Microsoft would want me to use the Cloud version. I have uninstalled it. I want to know if there is a technical reason to have left it on.

Saving your documents to OneDrive and installing Office 365 is two separate entirely independent activities. Office 365 is NOT a cloud version of Office, it’s a subscription to Office, OneDrive is a cloud file hosting service. OneDrive storage is included in the subscription to Office 365.

The only reason Office 365 would have been installed is if the Microsoft Account you logged into Office had an Office 365 associated with it.  Office 365 cannot be installed without a subscription to Office 365.  Office 2016 is a specific build of Office 365 at a specific point in time with only security updates being released for it. At this time Office 2016 does receive security updates but that changes on October 14, 2025.

The last update on November 14 2023 was build 16924.20150

Comment: This is only an observation, in my experience a retail perpetual license of office will seemingly upgrade, to the current Office 365 when the Microsoft Account that’s logged into within Office (which can be different than the one logged into Windows) has an active Office 365 subscription. You can stop that from happening by using the Office installation configuration tools.